# How to flag something to suggest a move to a better site when it is already closed?

Tags: discussion, migration

I came across this question today, [How to name variables with units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157466/how-to-name-variables-with-units), which, I agree with the closure on *this* site.   While I would find it difficult to edit this question to be within the scope of SO, this type of question is much more fitting on [software engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).   However, I cannot flag for migration, as it was already closed.

Though other parts of the question ask for opinions, it essentially **actually** just asks:

> "How can I add the unit to the code so I actually know what I am dealing with"

or

> "**In Java** how can I incorporate units of measure in my code so the programmer knows the units being used?"

And indeed there are a few good answers there answering this very question. Again, I would agree that this type of question shouldn't be on stack overflow, but I don't think this question is that far away from being a pretty decent software engineering SE question, really there's only one phrase that makes it not fit (too opinionated):

> "Should I name it like massInKg, even though it doesn't look good ?"

but this is clearly non-essential and can be re-phrased to show prior effort.

Answer (score -1):

If you're really, really sure the question should be migrated to another site, and it's less than 60 days old ([older questions can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/295232)), use a custom moderator flag. ♦ moderators are able to migrate them (by reopening the question and closing it again, this time choosing the 'migrate to another site' option). This question is from 2016, so it cannot be migrated anymore.

An out-of-the-box option would be to re-ask it on another site (or, if the author of the question is still active on Stack Exchange, ask him/her to do it). If you properly [reference](/help/referencing) the question, tailor it to the audience of that site and explain *why* you re-ask it (especially what you're missing in the current answers), it might work.

Comment: Oh, OK, its definitely older than 60 days, I'm not sure what to do, because the question seems like its close to being fine on SoftEng SE and there are actual useful contributions in answers.

Comment: also the question itself is useful, and doesn't have anything anywhere else